# Select two words of time period from a string in Pandas column and convert to number of days

Tags: python, pandas

```
df.column_1:
had 2 months of ownership
had 1 week of ownership
had 2 years of ownership
```

I want to convert ownership time to date in `df.column_1`. The expected output is:

```
df.column_1:
60
7
730
```

Below is what I have so far:

```
df['column_1'] = df['column_1'].str.split(r'\D').str.get(1)
```

But this only gives the second string (e.g. 2, 1, 2). I was planning to get second and third strings (e.g. 2 months) and convert them to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the number and period text (day/week/month/year).  Then, replace the period text with a multiplication sign `*` followed by the corresponding number of days to make a formula (e.g.  `2 *30` for 2 months).  Then, use [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) to evaluate the values of the formula:

```
df['result'] = (df['column_1'].str.extract(r'(\d+\s*\w+)')[0]
                              .replace({r'days?': '*1', 
                                        r'weeks?': '*7', 
                                        r'fortnights?': '*14', 
                                        r'months?': '*30',  
                                        r'years?': '*365'}, regex=True)
                              .apply(pd.eval)
               )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

                    column_1  result
0  had 2 months of ownership      60
1    had 1 week of ownership       7
2   had 2 years of ownership     730
```

Comment: Very nice solution, even works with strings with deviations from the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the strings in `column_1` follow the same pattern, you can prepare a dictionary for the time period terms.

Preparing the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

t="""had 2 months of ownership
had 1 week of ownership
had 2 years of ownership"""
df = pd.DataFrame(t.split('\n'), columns=['c1'])
df
```

Output

```
                          c1
0  had 2 months of ownership
1    had 1 week of ownership
2   had 2 years of ownership
```

To make it easier removing the `s` from the strings.

```
d = { 'day': 1, 'week': 7, 'month': 30, 'year': 365}
df['c1_in_days'] = df.c1.str.split().apply(lambda x: int(x[1])*d[x[2].replace('s','')])
df
```

Output

```
                          c1  c1_in_days
0  had 2 months of ownership          60
1    had 1 week of ownership           7
2   had 2 years of ownership         730
```